# Execute next 5 AJAX functions if previous 5 ajax functions is done

Tags: ajax

I have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#send').click(function({
        var foo = array(1,2,...,50);

        var max = 5;

        for(var i == 0; i < max; i++){
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ajax.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    id: foo[i]
                }
                ......
        })

    }));


</script>
```

I want script to check if five ajax functions is done, next 5 ajax functions will execute. Until all elements of foo were send to ajax.php, that's it!

I need your help.My english is not good, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var foo = new Array(50);
var max = 5;
var pointer = 0;

var batchSuccesses = 0;
var batchFailures = 0;


function runNextIfBatchCompleted(){
    if(batchSuccesses+batchFailures == max){
      batchSuccesses = 0;
      batchFailures = 0;
      runPostBatch();
    }
}

function runPostBatch(){
  var currentPointer = pointer;

  for(var i = currentPointer; i < Math.min(max*((currentPointer/max)+1),foo.length); i++){
    $.post('/ajax.php',
       { 'id' : foo[i] }
    )
    .done(function(data){
      batchSuccesses++;
      runNextIfBatchCompleted();
    })
    .fail(function(data){
      batchFailures++;
      runNextIfBatchCompleted();
    })
   pointer++;
  }
}

runPostBatch();
```

This uses the `jqXHR` interface offered by the jQuery library to allow us to trigger `done` / `fail` when we complete a batch of 5.

You can see this in action here: https://codepen.io/rhericlya/pen/XqvpWp in your console and network tab. (This uses `Get` rather than `Post` but otherwise is identical)

You can definitely improve on the efficiency of this code, but hopefully it gives you an idea of where to start.

Comment: Thank you, I am going try this!

Comment: Awesome! You're god!